# "negligible" random variables

Tags: distributions, random-variable

I would like to ask if the concept of 'negligible' random variables exist.

For example, if $X$ and $Y$ are random variables, not necessarily independent, then the sum $X+Y$ is, for all intents and purposes, is similar to $X$. This means that the contribution of $Y$ is 'negligible'.

Is there such a concept, and are there any texts/papers to this?

Thanks for your ideas.

Comment: "Negligible," like other comparative adjectives "larger," "worse then," "richer," etc., is in the eye of the beholder (and subject to assessment in light of their "intents and purposes"): it has no universal definition.  Is a loss of a million euros "negligible"?  To a large bank, yes; to a small business, absolutely not.  So yes, there is such a concept--but its discussion is not likely to be on topic on this site unless you can provide a specific context.

Comment: I was thinking of something like this: The pdf of $X+Y$ is obviously different from $X$ alone. But when you sketch the graph of the pdf of $X+Y$ and $X$, both differ only in scale, but the shape (or i don't know how else to describe) is similar.

Comment: In which case, it would be simpler to ignore $Y$ and focus on $X$ instead. Also, I was wondering if there is a 'quantifiable' explanation on how you can ignore the contribution of $Y$ in such a case.

Comment: It might not be useful to conflate the concepts of "negligible," "scale," and "shape." Please note that (1) the PDF of $X+Y$ can identical to that of $X$; (2) in other circumstances the PDF of $X+Y$ can be completely different from that of either $X$ or $Y$, differing in scale, shape, or both; and (3) because $X$ and $Y$ enter into the situation completely symmetrically, it accomplishes nothing to "ignore" one of them.  Thus, where you refer to the "contribution" of $Y$, to what exactly is it "contributing"?

Comment: I only have a qualitative description. The graph of $X$ and $X+Y$  are similar, as if $Y$ wasn't there. I have no further information as well, because I am not familiar with such a case. The reason I asked is because the sum is oftentimes difficult to solve, most especially if $X$ and $Y$ are not independent. So maybe it would help to do some sort of "comparison" as we do in algebra.

Comment: $X$ and $Y$ are supposed to be random variables. Do you really, then, mean the graph of $X+Y$ or do you mean the graphs of the *distribution functions* of $X$ and $X+Y$?  As I mentioned in case $1$, [it is possible](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_distribution#Properties) for $X$ and $Y$ to be *identically distributed* and yet have the distribution functions of $X$, $Y$, and $X+Y$ be identical.  Which of $X$ and $Y$ is supposed to be considered "negligible" in such a case?

Comment: It's subjective. Depends on the variance of $X$ as well as the risk-tolerance to variance. For milling a door, $\pm$ a tenth of an ml is negligible. For intake valves on a car, it could the difference between a functional engine and brick. As a statistician, just describe the MSE of X+Y as a proxy for X.